# How do I paste from vim to other apps with linux?

Tags: vim

I'm trying out vim after being a long term user of textmate, and while I can see the appeal of the app, even something as simple as selecting all on vim called on the a command line to paste into another app seems needlessly complex.

How do you make whatever you yank into the buffer available to other apps?

At present, I'm typing `ggvG` to select the whole file, and then typing `y` to yank it into the buffer, but this buffer isn't available to other apps.

I'm using Ubuntu Jaunty (the stock netbook remix install) and I'm using vim 7.2.79.

Also, is there a way to get a simple gui wrapper vim this as well, like how you have with [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)?

Comment: Ah, thanks CMS.

This seems to have resolved it, though I'm still somewhat puzzled as to why this should take 3 keystrokes.

Is there a good reason people don't bind this to crtl+c for adding to the universal clipboard like the rest of the planet?

Comment: Probably because `Ctrl-C` is more traditionally the keystroke for sending SIGINT to a running process, and Vim was a console app before it was a GUI app, so Vim uses `Ctrl-C` as an interrupt command also.  You can easily rebind it yourself.  `vmap <C-c> "+y` or something similar.  But read `:h map_CTRL-c` first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are lots of options for this:

Copy to the middle click register (selection clipboard):

```
gg"*yG
```

Copy to the copy-and-paste clipboard

```
gg"+yG
```

These both work by using `gg` to go to the start of the file, `"+` or `"*` select the register, `y` starts the yank and `G` is a motion to the end of the file.

To use the visual approach, you would do `ggvG"+y` (or replace `+` with `*` for the selection register).

Use command mode to do the same:

```
:%yank "
" Or:
:%yank +
```

For more information, see:

```
:help :yank
:help quoteplus
```

To use the `*` register by default, you can do:

```
:set clipboard=unnamed
```

This allows you to use `ggyG` or `:%yank` (without a register specifier) and then middle click to paste.

```
:help 'clipboard'
```

Comment: and if this is too much to type, then define some mappings for the relevant commands in your .vimrc

Answer (score 4):

Copy your text to the * register:

```
  gg"*yG
```

Then middle-click on any application to paste it..

Comment: This requires +xterm_clipboard - see :version - which I think is only available in "big Vim" on Ubuntu. The default Vim is the minimal version that had lots of features disabled at compile time!

Comment: Installing the vim-gtk package got this working for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Why not "select with mouse" - "paste with middle button" pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, hanging my head in shame.

Just discovered gvim in accessories on ubuntu.

Comment: Oh hang on, this still doesn't solve the pasting problem - I'm still unable to paste from vim to other apps.

Is this standard behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

- in vim: gg SHIFT+v G "+y
- in other app: middle button or ctrl+v